# How to get the host name in spring configuration file?

Tags: spring, hostname

Is there any easy way to get the host name in spring configuration file ? Currently I am using Java code to get the host name and and auto wire the property in the bean . But looking for less coding approach if any !

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The following will give you the hostname in java

```
return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

where InetAddress belongs to the java.net package.  You can add that to your java configuration file.  If you want to do it in xml, you can do the following

```
<bean id="localhostInetAddress"
    class="java.net.InetAddress"
    factory-method="getLocalHost"/>

<bean id="hostname"
    factory-bean="localhostInetAddress"
    factory-method="getHostName"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to refer to the hostname string as a property value from another bean in this file?  I had no luck with <property name="logging-source-host" value="sometext-{$hostname}" /> even though I confirmed that the hostname bean should be a String.  This gave me the error: Could not resolve placeholder 'HOSTNAME' in string value "sometext-{$hostname}"

Comment: What worked for me was the localhostInetAddress bean definition along with something like <property name="logging-source-host" value="sometext-#{localhostInetAddress.hostName}" />   I deleted the id="hostname" bean definition.